Proving Similarity of 2 Matrices
I am given two matrices $U$ and $V$. I'm also given that $U=JK$ and $V=KJ$, where $J$ is an invertible matrix. I am supposed to prove similarity but I'm unsure if my proof is sufficient.
$$V=KJ$$
$$VJ^{-1}=KJ  J^{-1}$$
$$VJ^{-1}=K \Bbb I$$
$$VJ^{-1}=K$$
I then substituted this into the equation for $U$
$$U=JK$$
$$U=JVJ^{-1}$$
I believe this satisfies the definition of a similar matrix as $B=PAP^{-1}$. My professor hasn't gone over any proofs with us, only computation, so I would not be surprised if I made a mistake here or misinterpreted the question.

Your proof is correct.

What you have is fine.  One small detail, why do you use * to indicate multiplication in one place and juxtaposition in another.   I would get rid of the stars.  You might want to make a brief note that you can right multiply by $J^{-1}$ because it is given that $J$ is invertible.

This is correct (though as a stylistic note, the $*$s indicating multiplication aren't necessary).
